# Simple click show() does nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I might be losing my mind here:

```
<span class="showMap" style="cursor:pointer;">(Show map)</span>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="map" style="height:300px; display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, DIV `#map` is set to not display, on clicking DIV `.showMap` I want it to show:

```
$( ".showMap" ).click(function() {
    alert('hey'); // for testing -> works perfectly 
    $('#map').show();
});
```

But it does nothing. No errors, nothing in console.

The hidden DIV contains a google map, not sure if that makes any difference but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Do you have the code wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(){});`?  The elements below that map may be taking longer to load.

Comment: is there any style applied to `#map` like `visibility:hidden` or something which would stop it from showing up.

Comment: There are known issues displaying Google Maps in this manner in some browsers. Use the inspector to determine whether the div is in fact showing, but the map is not.

Comment: If you inspect your code using developer tools then do you see the CSS of `#map` getting changed at all?

Comment: @KevinBowersox Yeah its wrapped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Maps does not like being hidden when it is being loaded. Think of jquery's `height()` function - it will return a wrong value when the element is hidden.

I'm not sure this will work, but using CSS have you `#map` as `position:absolute;left:-9999em;` so that it appears off-screen. This might allow Google Maps to load correctly. On the click function you will then want to `hide()` the map element, change the css to `position:relative;left:0;` and then `show()` it.

```
jQuery(function($){
  var map = $('#map');
  map.css({position:'absolute',left:'-9999em'});
  $('.showMore').click(function(){
    map.hide().css({position:'relative',left:'0em'}).show();
  });
});
```

Comment: The multiple selectors didn't work the way you coded them, never seen it like that before... when I changed it to: map.css('position','absolute').css('left','-9999em'); && map.hide().css('position','relative').css('left','0em').show(); it worked fine. Many thanks!

Comment: I do apologise, I got the syntax wrong. The css function can take an object of multiple `key:'value'` pairs allowing you to alter multiple css properties in one command as opposed to multiple `.css()` calls. What I did wrong was wrap the key in a quote as well. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/snowburnt/q392B/

put something in the div, then you'll see it open.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="map" style="height:300px;display:none;background-color:green">hello</div>
</div>
```

it doesn't look like there is anything there, because the background is white and there's nothing in the DIV. (also, as answered above, google maps doesn't like not being displayed).  So your code is working, just not displaying anything.

Comment: Thanks - If I add a word and not the map yeah that works, surely setting the height is enough though?

Comment: can you make a fiddle or modify mine to demonstrate?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney You do not need to add any word. Without adding any word or space you can achieve the functionality.

Comment: @VishalPatel based on code provided nothing would appear, would you contest this?

Comment: @Snowburnt Why so can you explain ?

Comment: @VishalPatel copy the code provided into a fiddle and tell me what appears to happen (without any examination of the elements).

Answer (score -1):

Try this... [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q392B/13/)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $( ".showMap" ).click(function() {
        alert('hey'); // for testing -> works perfectly 
        $('#map').css('display','');
    });    
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't have to deviate from standard jQuery for this. Hide() handles display states already.

Comment: I'm not saying that your code doesn't work. I'm saying that it's not a solution to the question posed.

Comment: @isherwood Care to explain?

Comment: What's to explain? You're merely replacing show() with css(), which does nothing to get a Google map to appear.

Comment: @isherwood Let me know if i am wrong, If you check jsFiddle link , What i see both vishal and richard are doing same thing hiding and showing Div . Correct me if i am wrong .

Comment: The map loads partially in Chrome. IE10 won't even let the Google maps iframe load, which is an unrelated issue. The point is, the div must be visible and the right size for Gmaps to load.

Comment: @isherwood Ok so this is an issue related to map, What i mean while working with maps ,It should be visible , but we can workaround by positioning Div.